# What does it mean when a dependency version in the POM file is red?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

In the POM file of an Intellij Maven project, sometimes the version value of a `dependency` is colored red. What exactly does this signify? Can I ignore it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could mean a number of things but most commonly it means that the version that is specified cannot be found in the repositroy you are looking in.
If your dependency is on a project that you've manually upgraded, you should make sure you've deployed it.

Also, the exact reasoning is normally written down when you hover over it (I know that in eclipse it's also written at the top).

Answer (score 2):

It sometimes happens when you haven't imported/updated your dependencies yet. For example, in IntelliJ IDEA I usually get this button on top right corner: [The button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Og00.png)

UPDATE: To avoid this in future you can enable "Auto import" for your pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

You should click File->Invalidate caches/restart and it solved my problem. This solved my red color problem.